# how to write testcases for android RESTful webservices

Tags: android-testing

how to write testcases for android RESTful webservices. I didnt found any sample test case for android. If you found any link or post on android RESTful webservices plz add. I have attached sample code down.

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        findViewById(R.id.my_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
        b.setClickable(false);
        new LongRunningGetIO().execute();
    }

    private class LongRunningGetIO extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String> {

        protected String getASCIIContentFromEntity(HttpEntity entity) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
           InputStream in = entity.getContent();
             StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
             int n = 1;
             while (n>0) {
                 byte[] b = new byte[4096];
                 n =  in.read(b);
                 if (n>0) out.append(new String(b, 0, n));
             }
             return out.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
             HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
             HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.hindu.com/rss/23hdline.xml");
             String text = null;
             try {
                   HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
                   HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                   text = getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 return e.getLocalizedMessage();
             }
             return text;
        }   

        protected void onPostExecute(String results) {
            if (results!=null) {
                EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.my_edit);
                et.setText(results);
            }
            Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
            b.setClickable(true);
        }
    }
}

main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Http GET Demo"/>
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="GET"
        android:id="@+id/my_button"/>
    <EditText 
        android:layout_margin="20dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minLines="15"
        android:maxLines="15"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:editable="false"
        android:id="@+id/my_edit"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to test? the result of the call to  `http://www.hindu.com/rss/23hdline.xml`?

Comment: 1.the HTTP response code
2.other HTTP headers in the response
3.the payload (JSON, XML)